# Remote Desktop Connection not showing shared directories

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I am using remote desktop from Windows XP to connect to a remote computer (Windows Server 2008 Standard SP1). When establishing the connection I told it to share my local drives. This shows up in the saved .rdp file:

```
drivestoredirect:s:*
```

However, when I use this to connect to the remote machine, I don't see any new drives in My Computer. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I needed to tweak this for a lab Win-10 system.  Is this a new default setting due to increased security?  (Seems so.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to ensure the RDP server doesn't have a policy set to disallow drive redirection.

If you have access, check the local/group policy `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection\Do not allow drive redirection`

If this is enabled you won't be able to connect your client drives, regardless of your RDP client settings.

More info from Microsoft [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791794(v=ws.10).aspx)